# UMVUE for $\frac{p}{1-p}$

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

Given a random sample of $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ of the negative binomial distribution $Nb(N,p)$, I am instructed to find the UMVUE for the parameter $\frac{1-p}{p}$.

In general, the mean $\mu$ of the negative binomial is given by the formula $\frac{N(1-p)}{p}$, and the UMVUE for $\mu$ is the sample mean $\overline X$. So essentially I'm asked to find the UMVUE for the parameter $\frac{\mu}{N}$.

So, would the UMVUE for $\frac{\mu}{N}$ be $\frac{\overline X}{N}$? This seems intuitively correct to me -since it indeed is an Unbiased estimator of $\frac{\mu}{N}$, and its variance is dropping by a lot (it's inversely proportional to $N^2$)- but I can't seem to find a way to prove this (or get to any result at all) using Lehmann–Scheffé theorem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just in case this helps someone else in the future, it seems the above is true (thanks to the invisible upvoter too, for hinting that it is), and not only that; turns out that: If a function $h$ is an UMVUE for the parameter $g(p)$, then the function $c \cdot h$ will be the UMVUE for the parameter $c \cdot g(p)$ - proof is the same as the Lehmann–Scheffé theorem proof, using mean values properties.

Comment: Your title says $\frac{p}{1-p}$ while your first paragraph says $\frac{1-p}{p}$.  An unbiased estimator for one will not be an unbiased estimator for the other; nor will its reciprocal be an unbiased estimator for the other

Comment: Yeah the one on the title is wrong, the parameter I was looking to estimate is $\frac{1-p}{p}$. Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply the Lehman-Scheffé Theorem, we require a complete sufficient statistic $S(\boldsymbol{x})$ for $\theta=(1-p)/p$ and an unbiased estimator $T(S)$ of $\theta$. Starting from the pmf of our data:
\begin{equation}
P(X_i=x_i)=\binom{x_i+N-1}{x_i}(1-p)^{x_i} p^N.
\end{equation}
Consider two sample points $\boldsymbol{x}$ and $\boldsymbol{y}$. Since
\begin{equation}
\frac{P(\boldsymbol{x};p)}{P(\boldsymbol{y};p)}=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^{n}\binom{x_i+N-1}{x_i}(1-p)^{x_i} p^N}{\prod_{i=1}^{n} \binom{y_i+N-1}{y_i}(1-p)^{y_i} p^N}\propto (1-p)^{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i-\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i},
\end{equation}
does not depend on $p$ if and only if $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i=\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i$, we may conclude that $S(\boldsymbol{x})=\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i$ is a minimally sufficient statistic for $p$ by a result of Lehman and Scheffé ($1950$).

Noting that $X_i$ is in the exponential family,
\begin{align}
P(x_i;p)&=e^{\ln \phi(x_i)+x_i\ln(1-p)+N\ln p},\\
&=e^{h(x_i)+A(p)t(x_i)+B(p)},
\end{align}
we have that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} t(x_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i=S(\boldsymbol{x})$ is a complete statistic, since the parameter space of $p$ contains an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ (this is a well known result in most mathematical statistics textbooks).

The conditions used above hold when considering any 'nice' transformation of $p$ (we may have written our pmf in terms of $\theta$ and derived the same results). So, $S(\boldsymbol{x})=\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i$ is a complete sufficient statistic for $\theta$.

Now let's consider your claim that $T(S)=\bar{X}/N=S/nN$ is the MVUE (one may also find such a $T$ from the Rao-Blackwell Theorem). Since
\begin{align}
E\left[T(S)\right]&=E\left[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i}{nN}\right],\\
&=\frac{1}{nN}\sum_{i=1}^{n}E[x_i],\\
&=\frac{1}{nN}\frac{Nn(1-p)}{p},\\
&=\frac{1-p}{p},\\
&=\theta,
\end{align}
we have that $T(S)$ is an unbiased estimator for $\theta$ and is a function of the complete sufficient statistic $S$ for $\theta$. Hence, by the Lehman-Scheffé Theorem, $T(S)$ is the UMVUE for $\theta$.

Comment: Magnificent! To be honest I didn't quite catch the part in which you prove that $S(\boldsymbol{x})=\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i$ is a sufficient statistic for P, and I'm on a quite difficult place to look into it thoroughly now, but I'll scan it once I get home. The rest of your explanation was really easy to grasp the way you presented it. Thanks a lot!!